# How to get clearInterval() to work in a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

So I'm trying to get a function to run once every second, and then after four seconds I want it to stop using `clearInterval()`

```
function dotdotdot(){
var x = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    if (x>=3){
    torpWri = torpWri + ".";
    document.getElementById("torpTxt").innerHTML = torpWri;
    x++;
    }
    else{
        x = 0;
        clearInterval();
    }
    },1000);
}
```

This is my function and it should stop after four seconds and then reset x to 0 for when I call it again.

```
function loadButton(){
torpWri = "Torpedo Loading"
if(torpLoadAmount[arNum]<5){
    torpLoadAmount[arNum]++;
    torpAmount--;
    document.getElementById("torpCnt").innerHTML = torpAmount;
    document.getElementById("torpTxt").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("butunload").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("butfire").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("torpTxt").innerHTML = torpWri;
    dotdotdot();
}
else{
    document.getElementById("torpTxt").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("torpTxt").innerHTML = "Torpedo Bay Full";
}
timer3();
}
```

This is how I'm calling it.
I'm just needed to know why it isn't running the function `dotdotdot();` every second and then stopping after four. Then when I call it again it should all just reset. But it's not running...

I've been searching for a while and haven't found anything, so I came here.

(Also, please don't comment on my other code, I know there are probably easier ways to do it, but this is what I'm working with right now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` returns a timerID, which needs to be passed to `clearInterval`.

```
var ticks = 0;
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
  if (++ticks == 4) {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
}, 1000);
```

You could also use `setTimeout` instead, and just not schedule a new tick when the condition is met.

```
setTimeout(function callback(ticks) {
  if (ticks > limit) {
    return;
  }

  setTimeout(callback, 0, ++ticks);
}, 1000, 0)
```

Comment: That worked really well for me. I didn't know that you could just set the setInterval(); function to a variable. Thanks for solving that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the handle / intervalId for the interval when it is set and then use it when you want to clear the interval:

```
function dotdotdot(){
    var x = 0;
    var intervalId = -1;
    intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        if (x>=3){
            torpWri = torpWri + ".";
            document.getElementById("torpTxt").innerHTML = torpWri;
            x++;
        } else {
            x = 0;
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Comment: Why'd you set intervalId = -1?

Comment: No reason. Not required. In my implementation/ use case I was reverting the intervalId back to -1 as a 'reset'. I was using an interval multiple times, intermittently. The -1 was an indicator that the job wasn't running

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` will return a `timerid`. So do like

```
var timer = setInterval(fun......)
```

Then

```
clearInterval(timer)
```